# I want to run PHP code when an image is clicked using jQuery (or ajax)

Tags: php, facebook

I have got the following code to show a dialog box when the image is clicked. Instead of running FB.ui I want to run PHP code. It's for facebook.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style> img#share_button { cursor: pointer; } </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId  : 'xxx',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is the image:

```
<img id = "share_button" src = "img.png">
```

And this is the code I need to change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#share_button').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'TabPress1',
            link: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/',
            picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/',
            caption: 'I am a fan of TabPress',
            description: 'TabPress -- Gotta love it!',
            message: ''
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know any JS, hope you can help me!

Comment: Do you need the result of the PHP-Script?

Comment: php and javascript are 2 different things and run differently. Javascript is on the client side while php on the server side

Comment: @AlexandruRosianu Okay, have a look at my answer then.

Comment: Does the `FB.ui()` code work for you? Why replace it with php?

Comment: @jrummell when the user clicks the image I need to perform some checks before showing the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know any javascript, perhaps it's best if you check out some beginner tutorials, like those at http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/javascript-ajax/?tag=basix , but in regard to your question...

It looks like your using jQuery. The best way to do what your describing is to use AJAX, and jQuery has nice functionality for that.

To select an element from the DOM based on it's ID in jQuery, just do this:

```
$("#TheIdOfYourImage")
```

now, to listen for when it's been clicked,

```
$("#TheIdOfYourImage").click(function(){
   //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Now, for the AJAX fun. You can read the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ for more technical details, but this is what it boils down to

```
        $("#TheIdOfYourImage").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",                                 // If you want to send information to the PHP file your calling, do you want it to be POST or GET. Just get rid of this if your not sending data to the file
              url: "some.php",                             // The location of the PHP file your calling
              data: "name=John&location=Boston",           // The information your passing in the variable1=value1&variable2=value2 pattern
              success: function(result){ alert(result) }   // When you get the information, what to do with it. In this case, an alert
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use an href attribute with removing underlying and coloring of the link and launch your php script?

Comment: I don't want to launch it in a new window if this is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

to run a javascript function when button is clicked:

```
<img id = "share_button" src = "img.png" onclick = "dothis()">
```

here is some basic javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function dothis(){
alert("Button pressed");
}
</script>
```

This is just some basic javascript that will make a message appear on the screen when the button is clicked

EDIT: It appears you want to use JSON. Take a look at this:
http://ditio.net/2008/07/17/php-json-and-javascript-usage/

Comment: The languages serve two different purposes. PHP is a server-side language and is used for backend functionality while JS is a client-side language and is used for frontend (things that the user directly notices).

Perhaps you could try using JSON (a form of AJAX request)?

Answer (score 0):

As you have jQuery already there: Send an AJAX-Request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#share_button').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax('/path/to/your/script.php');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

cf. the jQuery documentation for further information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Additionally I added CDATA-Tags to avoid problems with HTML-Special-Chars. These special chars would normally have to be encoded.

Comment: Actually I do need a result, I will use Joseph Szymborski's code

Answer (score 0):

The FB.ui(param1,param2) method can take two parameters.  You've specified the first one that dictates how the feed dialog is displayed.  Param2 can be your callback function

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

In the code switch for `post was published`, you can then use jQuery to make an AJAX call to one of your PHP pages.  See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I want the PHP code to decide if the dialog should be shown or not

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think you want to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // on click
    $('#share_button').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // any parameters you need to pass to your php script, 
        // you can omit the data parameter if you don't need it
        var data = { param1: "a", param2: 2 }; 

        // start the ajax request
        $.post("your/script.php", data, function() {

            // when the ajax request completes, show the FB dialog
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'TabPress1',
                link: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/',
                picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/',
                caption: 'I am a fan of TabPress',
                description: 'TabPress -- Gotta love it!',
                message: ''
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Relevant javascript references:

- [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [FB.ui()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)